# Get values from ng-repeat and store in a list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm starting with Angular and JS.

This is my controller and HTML:

```
app.controller('ControllerProfesores',function($scope, $http){
      $scope.listProfesores = [];
      $scope.getProfesores = function(){
            $http.get("profesores")
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.listProfesores = response.data;
            });
      };
});


<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="profesor in listProfesores">
       <p id="test">{{profesor.nombre}}</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is get the values from {{profesor.nombre}} and store them in a list, so I can do stuff like that:

```
<script>
       var list; //{{profesor.nombre}} values
       for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
             document.write('<b>'+list[i]+'</b>');
       }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you already have that inside listProfesores . why do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you want to get all `nombre`? You can do that just iterating the `listProfesores`, however if you want to do it: `nombres = $scope.listProfesores.map(x => x.nombre);`